# Powershell - Filter results of varaible in pipeline

Tags: powershell

I want to limit the results of the $Groups variable below to only return members of a specific group. This code retrieves the groups a computer belongs to. I am interested only in those that are members of any AD group that contains "SCCM".

I tried line 5 but that doesn't work. What is the correct method to do this? Thanks.

```
    $SamAccountNames = (Get-ADComputer Computer).SamAccountName
    $OSInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName Computer
    $ServerGroupMemberShipList = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $SAMAccountNames | Sort SAMAccountName 
    $Groups = $ServerGroupMemberShipList.Name 
    #$Groups = $ServerGroupMemberShipList.Name | Select {$ServerGroupMemberShipList.Name -like "SCCM"}
    Write-Host " "
    Write-Host "Checking Software Updates Compliance on" $Computer.ToUpper() -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
    Write-Host $OSInfo.Caption
    $Groups
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the `Select-Object` cmdlet, try using the `Where-Object` cmdlet for filtering or `?` for short. The `$_` variable is the current object being processed by the cmdlet.

```
$Groups = $ServerGroupMemberShipList | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "SCCM" }
```

or

```
$Groups = $ServerGroupMemberShipList | ? { $_.Name -like "SCCM" }
```

Comment: I forgot to say I did try that but the $Groups come us empty. Perhaps I am going about it wrong.

If I run line 4 the way it is, it returns:
Domain Controllers
SCCM-Server-Patching-0530

As you can see, I am trying to limit the collection to those AD groups that have "SCCM" in the name.